# Reentering a country with a different nation's passport

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, visa-free-entry

I'm a dual national, with two passports.

If I'm revisiting a country, which I've already visited in the past (over 1 year ago) with Passport A - would presenting Passport B to the immigration officer cause problems, knowing that Passport B does not contain previous Arrival/Departure stamps which are present in Passport A?

For what it's worth - both passports allow for Visa-Free entry and I have not overstayed/attempting to get around any Visa-Free restrictions.

This is not a duplicate as this is specifically about using dual passports to enter a third country.

Comment: This is not a duplicate: the other question is about using multiple passports while you travel, this is.about using multiple passports to enter the same country.

Comment: Anecdotally, I entered Turkey on a British passport in 2011 and entered again on a South African passport in 2015 and had no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it's fine, assuming everything else is in order and you're not trying to (for example) avoid X-days-in-Y restrictions by switching passports.

To expand on that a bit more, immigration laws are designed to control the movement of **people**, not passports.  As long as you as a person follow all applicable laws, including declaring other nationalities and previous entries when required, using different passports for travel is not an issue.  Sure, there may be Immigration officials who consider this *suspicious* and may ask you an extra question or two, but this *alone* is not going to suffice as grounds to deny entry in any country.  (Contrary to common perception, denying entry to a country for a person with valid docs has to be grounded in written regulation and usually requires approvals from supervisors etc.)

And finally, for those preferring anecdata over logic, I'm a dual citizen myself and have entered a long series of countries including but not limited to the US, Canada, Japan, New Zealand, Singapore, Thailand and the Philippines with passports of both my nationalities.  The only country that ever even asked about this was the US, and that's because [I had two ESTAs at the same time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39339/can-i-have-multiple-valid-estas-in-different-passports); when I stated that I used a different passport last time, I was granted entry with no further questions.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, this is literally just for curiosities sake, and potentially filling up my second passport with stamps :).

Comment: While this is generally true, there could be exceptions.

Comment: @phoog Such as?

Comment: @jpatokal any country that bothers to look up previous entries using another passport combined with a border officer who wants to make an issue of it.  There may even be countries that have regulations discouraging the practice.  I don't know of any examples, but I would certainly be wary of saying that it could never be a problem.