# USA visa runs with B-1/B-2 and Visa Waiver Program on two different passports?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas

For someone who has two non-US passports, one eligible for the Visa Waiver Program (European) and one not eligible for the Visa Waiver Program (Israeli) but which does hold a 10-year, multiple entry B-1/B-2, can they alternate the passports they enter the US on? From what I've read, it seems that "visa runs" either don't work (i.e. short travel to Canada/Mexico is counted as part of the stay in the US) or are frowned upon by the CBP (who may not allow an additional entry after a short stay outside the US). But if the US entries were spaced out between the two passports, could that help?

In this case, the person is married to a US citizen (expat) and thus could apply for a green card, but is not interested in becoming a US person since there are all sorts of tax and foreign account implications. But they are interested in spending a year or two traveling around the US.

[Can I have multiple valid ESTAs in different passports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39339/can-i-have-multiple-valid-estas-in-different-passports) addresses a similar question but for two ESTA-eligible passports.

Comment: Same name, date of birth, FINGERPRINTS and photo - all of which are collected at point of entry.  Nuff said?

Answer (score 2):

Visas (and ESTAs, etc.) are for *persons*, not for passports.

Whatever you do, applies to you and not to any of your passports - you *might* get away with it, but chances are slim if the names match, and if you get caught, it's pretty serious. You'd probably get blocked for 10 years, or even go to jail, for trying to cheat an immigration officer.

In addition, spending the majority of the year in the US already makes you tax filing liable.